# how to find Max_winning_streak (max number of consecutive +ve values) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, numpy-ndarray

I have datafram like This:

dataframe_name-> p_and_l

```
date             pnl
1/2/17 15:14    -907.5
1/3/17 15:14    1685.75
1/4/17 15:14    817
1/5/17 15:14    -182.5
1/6/17 15:14    415.25
1/9/17 15:14    -339.75
1/10/17 15:14   -413
1/11/17 15:14   1137.5
1/12/17 15:14   127.25
1/13/17 15:14   617.5
1/16/17 15:14   -875
1/17/17 15:14   158
1/18/17 15:14   -498.75
1/19/17 15:14   224.5
```

I tried to find Max_winning_streak (max number of consecutive +ve values) like this...
Max_winning_streak =  pd.Series(p_and_l['pnl'])
Max_winning_streak.apply(consecutiveCount)

But not getting the desired solution.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are "+ve values"? What is `consecutiveCount`? How is the output supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare values for groups by less ot equal `0` with cumulative sum and then count values, [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) sorting by default, so first value is maximal count:

```
m = df['pnl'].le(0)

max1 = m.cumsum()[~m].value_counts().iat[0]
print (max1)
3
```